# How to shorten/truncate a branch in ggtree

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo, ggtree

With a phylo tree generated with the R packages APE and plotting with ggtree - is anyone aware of a method to make branches shorter?

My angle is that I'm comparing mostly intra-species, but added the two most closely related species, partly to root the tree. However, the evolutionary distance from the closely related species is much higher than intra-species, of course, and this means that I have a super long branch that takes up too much space + it's harder to make out the details of the intra-species differences because the image gets zoomed out to show the other species.

The obvious manual solution is to alter the image outside of R, but I'd prefer a programming solution.

As far as I can see, ggtree has a 'zoom' function, but this is only concerned with width of a clade, not the depth. I have seen plots from ggtree with the sort of truncation that I've mentioned (showing the truncated region with a dotted line), but I'm unaware if these details were edited after finishing the plot.

[Here's the tree I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evYak.png)

Here's code to produce a tree with data from ape. The problem of truncation could be applied to most branches here, too.

```
library(ape)
library(ggtree)
data("woodmouse")
woodmouse %>% 
  dist.dna() %>% 
  nj() %>% 
  ggtree() + 
  ggtitle("Example") + 
  geom_treescale()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you include a minimal example with the question?

Comment: I added an image of the tree I'm working with.

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The example should include code which allows for your problem to be reproduced. It makes it much easier for people to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ggtree()
  xlim(-18, +25) + 
  ggtitle("Example") + 
  geom_treescale()
```